# Matching the JSON schema while receiving the data from client

Tags: python, json, rest, flask, pymongo

I wrote a Flask REST implementation to receive the following data.

After checking the API key from the client, the server should store the data which comes in the following API definition. The issue, I am facing is, I have got many strings under the same field 'services' where I would appreciate any help.

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "termsAndConditions": "string",
  "offererBranchId": "string",
  "requesterBranchId": "string",
  "accepted": "2017-05-24T10:06:31.012Z",
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "aggregationLevel": [
       "string"
      ],
      "aggregationMethod": [
        "string"
      ],
      "timestep": [
      "string"
      ]   
  ] 
  }
}
```

My code is below, if the field name 'services' has a single string with it, like the other ones (i.e "id","termsAndConditions" etc.).

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'demo'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://xxxx@xxxx.mlab.com:xxxx/demo'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
users = mongo.db.users
@app.route('/service-offer/confirmed/REQUESTER',methods=['POST'])

def serviceofferconfirmed():
    key = request.headers.get('X-API-Key')

    users=mongo.db.users
    api_record=users.find_one({'name':"apikey"})
    actual_API_key=api_record['X-API-Key']
    if key==actual_API_key:
        offer={"id": request.json["id"],
           "termsAndConditions":request.json["termsAndConditions"],
           "offererBranchId":request.json["offererBranchId"],
           "requesterBranchId": request.json["requesterBranchId"],
           "accepted":request.json["accepted"],
           "services":request.json["services"] # Here I need help to match the schema.
            }
        users.insert(offer)
        return "Service Data Successfully Stored"
    return jsonify("Pleae check your API Key or URL")
```

I wish to receive the whole data which are many strings and store the data under the field name 'services'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use isinstance("str", request.json["services"])

if you don't want value as string  for services

```
if not isinstance("str", request.json["services"]):
    //  your code..........
```